# Maxima of bivariate function

Tags: inequality, optimization

[1] Is there an easy way to formally prove that,
$$
2xy^{2} +2x^{2} y-2x^{2} y^{2} -4xy+x+y\ge -x^{4} -y^{4} +2x^{3} +2y^{3} -2x^{2} -2y^{2} +x+y$$
$${0<x,y<1}$$
without resorting to checking partial derivatives of the quotient formed by the two sides, and finding local maxima?

[2] Similarly, is there an easy way for finding $$\max_{0<x,y<1} [f(x,y)]$$
where,
$$f(x,y)=2x(1+x)+2y(1+y)-8xy-4(2xy^{2} +2x^{2} y-2x^{2} y^{2} -4xy+x+y)^{2}$$

Comment: Wolframalpha suggests that there the maximum is attained in two points: try
[maximize 2x(1+x)+2y(1+y)-8xy-4(2xy^2 +2x^2 y-2x^2 y^2 -4xy+x+y)^2 for 0<=x<=1, 0<=y<=1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+2x%281%2Bx%29%2B2y%281%2By%29-8xy-4%282xy%5E2+%2B2x%5E2+y-2x%5E2+y%5E2+-4xy%2Bx%2By%29%5E2+for+0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D1%2C+0%3C%3Dy%3C%3D1)
and [maximize 2x(1+x)+2y(1+y)-8xy-4(2xy^2 +2x^2 y-2x^2 y^2 -4xy+x+y)^2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+2x%281%2Bx%29%2B2y%281%2By%29-8xy-4%282xy%5E2+%2B2x%5E2+y-2x%5E2+y%5E2+-4xy%2Bx%2By%29%5E2)

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, there is no need for taking the quotient, since $a \ge b \Leftrightarrow \min \{a-b\} \ge 0$.

Here's a cool trick called the **S.O.S.** (sum of squares) method. The idea is to try and factor out $(x-y)^2$:

$$\begin{align}
LHS-RHS &=(x^4+y^4-2x^2y^2)-2(x^3+y^3-x^2y-xy^2)+2(x^2+y^2-2xy)\\
        &=(x^2-y^2)^2-2(x^2-y^2)(x-y)+2(x-y)^2\\
        &=(x-y)^2(x+y)^2-2(x-y)^2(x+y)+2(x-y)^2\\
        &=(x-y)^2((x+y)^2-2(x+y)+2)\\
        &=(x-y)^2((x+y-1)^2+1)\\
        &\ge 0
\end{align}$$

Note that this holds for all $x, y \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks much @Peteris, nice. And what about Q #2? I think it is more difficult... (analytically finding the max).

Answer (score 1):

Your first question:

With a little manipulation you get that it is equivalent to
$$x^2((1-x)^2+1)+y^2((1-y)^2+1) \ge 2xy[(1-x)(1-y)+1].$$

This can be obtained from addition of two inequalities
$$x^2(1-x)^2+y^2(1-y)^2 \ge 2xy(1-x)(1-y)$$
$$x^2+y^2\ge 2xy.$$

Both of them are special cases of $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$, which follows from $(a-b)^2\ge 0$. (Or, if you prefer, you can consider it as a special case of [AM-GM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_inequality) inequality.)

Note: To check the algebraic manipulations, you can simply compare the results for
[2xy^2 +2x^2 y-2x^2 y^2 -4xy+x+y - ( -x^4 -y^4 +2x^3 +2y^3 -2x^2 -2y^2 +x+y)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2xy%5E2+%2B2x%5E2+y-2x%5E2+y%5E2+-4xy%2Bx%2By+-+%28+-x%5E4+-y%5E4+%2B2x%5E3+%2B2y%5E3+-2x%5E2+-2y%5E2+%2Bx%2By%29)

[expand x^2((1-x)^2+1)+y^2((1-y)^2+1) -2xy[(1-x)(1-y)+1]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+x%5E2%28%281-x%29%5E2%2B1%29%2By%5E2%28%281-y%29%5E2%2B1%29+-2xy%5b%281-x%29%281-y%29%2B1%5d)

Or simply subtract the two expressions:

[2xy^2 +2x^2 y-2x^2 y^2 -4xy+x+y - ( -x^4 -y^4 +2x^3 +2y^3 -2x^2 -2y^2 +x+y) - [x^2((1-x)^2+1)+y^2((1-y)^2+1) -2xy[(1-x)(1-y)+1]]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2xy%5E2+%2B2x%5E2+y-2x%5E2+y%5E2+-4xy%2Bx%2By+-+%28+-x%5E4+-y%5E4+%2B2x%5E3+%2B2y%5E3+-2x%5E2+-2y%5E2+%2Bx%2By%29+-+%5bx%5E2%28%281-x%29%5E2%2B1%29%2By%5E2%28%281-y%29%5E2%2B1%29+-2xy%5b%281-x%29%281-y%29%2B1%5d%5d)

---

I did not succeed in finding similar type of solution for your second problem.

Comment: Thanks alsoh @Martin Sleziak. I think Q #2 is different in nature...